# model isn't loading in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

i have a model for a football stadium, i am using xna4.0, the visual studio 2015 can open it with its fbx viewer but when i load it to the project a got nothing the model have too much triangles so i used HiDef game profile and other model loading properly and the model was 3ds model but i converted it to fbx.
this is the drawing function:

```
private void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
        {
            Matrix[] modelTransforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {

                    effect.World =  world;
                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = projection;
                }

                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
    {
        Matrix[] modelTransforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];

        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(modelTransforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {

                effect.World =  world;
                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

Comment: didnt work btw it is a very big model could this be the problem?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. Could you edit your question and add whole class?